# Return first half of string, Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, split, palindrome

I'm struggling to find a way to return only the first half of a string.

I have a code that checks if a string is a palindrome, and if it is, I want to return only the first half using `Just`. If it is not a palindrome it should just return `Nothing`

Ex. `halfPalindrome "boy"` should return `Nothing` and `halfPalindrome "abba"` should return `Just "ab"`.

I've tried different things, but it seems as though I need a helper function.

```
halfPalindrome :: String -> Maybe String
halfPalindrome x = 
    if x == reverse x 
        then 
            Just half 
    else Nothing 


            
half :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
half xs = (take 1 xs, drop 1 xs) 
    where 1 = div (length xs) 2
```

I'm not sure how to implement/use my helper function correctly

**EDIT**

Final code works. Thank you guys :)

```
halfPalindrome :: String -> Maybe String
halfPalindrome x
  | x == reverse x = let (a, _) = half x in Just a
  | otherwise = Nothing

first_half :: [a] -> [a]
first_half = (\xs -> case xs of
            [] -> []
            xs -> take ((length xs) `div` 2 ) xs)

second_half :: [a] -> [a]
second_half = (\xs -> case xs of
            [] -> []
            xs -> drop ((length xs) `div` 2 ) xs)

half :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
half = (\xs -> case xs of
            [] -> ([],[])
            xs -> (first_half xs, second_half xs))
```

**shorter**

```
halfPalindrome :: String -> Maybe String
halfPalindrome x 
    | x == reverse x = let (a, _) = half x in Just a
    | otherwise = Nothing

half :: [a] -> ([a], [a]) 
half xs = 
    ((take s xs), (drop s xs))
    where
        s = (length xs ) `div` 2
```

Comment: Maybe you should pass `x` to `half`?

Comment: I still get an error for "Just half" ...

Comment: I didn't mean that passing `x` to `half` solves all your problems but it's one of many required steps.

Comment: Why did you write the type of `half` as `[a] -> ([a], [a])` and not as `[a] -> [a]`? It is supposed to take one string and return one string, isn't it?

Comment: In your `half`, try replacing all occurrences of `1` with a variable like `n`. Indeed, the equation `1 = ....` is trying to re-define `1` which makes no sense -- define `n` instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm making it difficult, but I thought it should take one string - then make two (since it splits in the middle). I'm sure [a] -> [a] is more correct though since I only want one string in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`half` is a function, you thus should call this with `x` and return the first part, so:

```
halfPalindrome :: String -> Maybe String
halfPalindrome x
  | x == reverse x = let (a, _) = half x in Just a
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

It is however *not* necessary to determine the `length` of the list to return the half. You can work with two "iterators" that "walk" over the same list, but where the second one takes "hops" of two, and thus if that one reaches the end of the list, the first one is located in the middle of the `String`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will read into how the "let"  "in" works now, but now the code does exactly what I wanted :))

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, using "length" when dividing a string just seemed intuitive. Maybe something else will make the code shorter as well! First week with Haskell, so I've got a lot to read in to haha